# Django: upload csv file and stays in memory

Tags: django

I'm trying to build a web app using Django where the user will upload some csv file, possibly a big one. Then the code will clean the file for bad data and then the user can use it to make queries with clean data.

Now I believe whenever a user will make a query, the whole code will run again which means it will start cleaning again and so on.

**Question:**

Is there any way that once the csv data in clean, it stays in memory and user can make queries to that clean data?

```
import pandas as pd

def converter(num):
    try:
        return float(num)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            num = num.replace("-", '0.0').replace(',', '')
            return float(num)
        except ValueError:
            return np.nan

def get_clean_data(request):
    # Read the data from csv file:
    df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

    # Clean the data and send JSON response
    df['month'] = df['month'].str.split("-", expand=True)[1]
    df[df.columns[8:]] = df[df.columns[8:]].astype(str).applymap(converter)
    selected_year = df[df["Departure Datetime: Year (YYYY)"] == 2015]
    data_for_user = (selected_year.groupby(
        by="route").sum().sort_values(by="revenue").to_json()

    return JsonResponse(data_for_user, safe=False)
```

Comment: Well you should store the *cleaned* file (in a file or in a database), not the raw CSV file.

Comment: I agree with the first commenter. That said, have you looked at using a tempfile to accomplish what you're describing? https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this could be to cache the dataframe in memory after it has been cleaned. Subsequent requests could then use the cleaned version from the cache.

```
from django.core.cache import cache

def get_clean_data(request):
    # Check the cache for cleaned data
    df = cache.get('cleaned_data')

    if df is None:
        # Read the data from csv file:
        df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

        # Clean the data
        df['month'] = df['month'].str.split("-", expand=True)[1]
        df[df.columns[8:]] = df[df.columns[8:]].astype(str).applymap(converter)

        # Put it in the cache
        cache.set('cleaned_data', df, timeout=600)

    selected_year = df[df["Departure Datetime: Year (YYYY)"] == 2015]
    data_for_user = (selected_year.groupby(
        by="route").sum().sort_values(by="revenue").to_json()

    return JsonResponse(data_for_user, safe=False)
```

You'd need to be a little bit careful, because if the csv file is very large it may consume a large amount of memory when cached.

Django supports a number of different [cache backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/#setting-up-the-cache), from simple [local memory caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching), to more complex [memcached caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/#memcached).